# XSLT transformation with multiple nodes

Tags: xslt

I have multiple occurence nodes which need to be generated at output using XSLT transformation. Could you please help me on this.

Following XSLT code only generate one node occurrence only. Could you please help me with below XSLT code how to generate multiple nodes elements in Input XML

Input XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
    <soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:getGenResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    <ns1:getGenReturn xsi:type="soapenc:Array" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[2]" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    </ns1:getGenReturn>
    </ns1:getGenResponse>
    <multiRef id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:Gen" xmlns:soapenc=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/>
        <name xsi:type="xsd:string">ULM</name> 
         <mail xsi:type="xsd:string">ulm@gmail.com</mail> 
    </multiRef>
    <multiRef id="id1" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns3:Gen" " xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <name xsi:type="xsd:string">ABC</name> 
         <mail xsi:type="xsd:string">abc@gmail.com</mail> 
    </multiRef>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

XSLT Code used for this transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" x
 xmlns:response="http://tempuri.org/" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<!-- Output -->
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:if test="//soap:Body/multiRef">
<xsl:element name="getGenResponse">
  <xsl:element name="getGenReturn">
                               <xsl:element name="name"><xsl:value-of select="//name"/></xsl:element>

                               <xsl:element name="mail"><xsl:value-of select="//mail"/></xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

   <!-- 'Copy ' node -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output from  above XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<getGenResponse>
   <getGenReturn>
      <name> ULM </name>
      <mail>ulm@gmail.com<mail>
   </getGenReturn>
/getGenResponse>
```

**Output expected**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<getGenResponse>
   <getGenReturn>
      <name> ULM </name>
      <mail>ulm@gmail.com<mail>
   </getGenReturn>
  <getGenReturn>
      <name>ABC</name>
      <mail>abc@gmail.com<mail>
  </getGenReturn>
/getGenResponse>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At you moment all you are doing is testing a `multiRef` element exists, and outputting only one new `getGenReturn` element.

All you really need to do is replace the `xsl:if` with `xsl:for-each` to select all the elements, then you will get one `getGenReturn` for each. And also change the `xsl:value-of` to use a relative path

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:element name="getGenResponse">
    <xsl:for-each select="//soap:Body/multiRef">
      <xsl:element name="getGenReturn">
        <xsl:element name="name"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="mail"><xsl:value-of select="mail"/></xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Or better still, do this, as `xsl:element` is not really needed here if you are using static names

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <getGenResponse>
    <xsl:for-each select="//soap:Body/multiRef">
      <getGenReturn>
        <name><xsl:value-of select="name"/></name>
        <mail><xsl:value-of select="mail"/></mail>
      </getGenReturn>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </getGenResponse>
</xsl:template>
```

Note, you don't actually need the identity template in this case. Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:response="http://tempuri.org/" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="soap response">

    <!-- Output -->
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <getGenResponse>
        <xsl:for-each select="//soap:Body/multiRef">
          <getGenReturn>
            <name><xsl:value-of select="name"/></name>
            <mail><xsl:value-of select="mail"/></mail>
          </getGenReturn>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </getGenResponse>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: yes, your code gives expected result but only <xsl:for-each select="//soap:Body/multiRef"> must be inside of <getGenResponse> node then I get my expected one. but your code ulitmately solves my problem

Comment: Hello Tim,

 I have another question here on , I have to process 'multiRef' records only if this element exist 'getGenResponse' from input XML file.  I tried the way it didn't help to me. Could you please help me on this as well

Comment: (or) either I want to validate xsi:type of 'multiRef' element for ex: xsi:type ='Gen' this is my source XML

Comment: I am not quite I follow what you want, so you might want to ask a whole new question, but perhaps you need to `<xsl:for-each select="//soap:Body[ns1:getGenResponse]/multiRef">`, or maybe `<xsl:for-each select="//soap:Body/multiRef[substring-after(@xsi:type, ':')='Gen']">`

Comment: Hello Tim, sorry this is a new question, with this code  <xsl:for-each select="//soap:Body['ns1:getGenResponse']/multiRef"> it could n't filter condition  and at the same time with this code <xsl:for-each select="//soap:Body/multiRef[substring-after(@xsi:type, ':')='Gen']"> following XSLT Error: Element type "xsl:for-each" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>

Comment: I think you should ask a whole new question here on Stackoverflow, as it is not easily to help about code in comments. Thank you!

Comment: ok Tim. No problem. I will create. I am new to this forum. First time it was really struggled to create a new question. that's reason i tried to use same question.

Comment: Hello Tim, yes, I declared xmlns:ns1="http://service.pen.eewe.en.de" in the XSLT. now I am able to execute the code with desired result.

Comment: Hello Tim, Could you please help me on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56887420/handling-multiple-for-loop-in-xslt

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:response="http://tempuri.org/" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="soap response">

    <!-- Output -->
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <getGenResponse>
        <xsl:for-each select="//soap:Body/multiRef">
          <getGenReturn>
            <name><xsl:value-of select="name"/></name>
            <mail><xsl:value-of select="mail"/></mail>
          </getGenReturn>
         </xsl:for-each>
        </getGenResponse>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```